# Does interrupting the SQL Server import and Export Wizard rollback the transaction?

Tags: sql, ssis

I am loading several large CSV (8 million rows a piece) into a local SQL Server instance. On one of them, when it was about 70,000 rows in, I realized that I made a mistake in the mappings so I hit Stop to interrupt it and cancelled the operation.

Did those 70,000 or so rows get inserted and create duplicates when I imported the same file again or is the whole transaction rolled back?

Comment: Hi It actually depends on how you have scripted. Why dont you check if there are any duplicates in the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are importing from the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard and you clicked on "Stop" during the "Copying to ..." Action, it does not automatically rollback the rows that were copied into the table before you clicked "Stop", those rows are in your table at that point.

To will need to manually delete those rows.

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't find the answer anywhere in the documentation.